# Ubuntu LAMP stack | Localhost not displaying

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp, phpmyadmin

I'm new to Linux and servers so please have patience. I did search for a solution, prior to posting this. I did find ONE question that was similar, but not the same and there was no solution so I am posting, asking in a different way, in hopes of finding the what's causing the problem as well as a solution to said problem.

Problem:

"http://localhost/" will not display anything in browser after LAMP install.

I followed instructions to a "T" and everything installed properly. I can access 127.0.0.1, phpmyadmin, apache, etc. but when I try to view "localhost" in the browser, I literally get nothing but a blank white page.

I have added **# ServerName 127.0.0.1 localhost** to the apache.conf file.

I am able to view localhost/phpmyadmin just fine but no http://localhost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I went to folder: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and changed this line: `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to `DocumentRoot /var/www`

and then I went to file: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and changed this line: `<Directory /var/www/html>` to `<Directory /var/www/>`

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 and I was able to solve the issue.

Comment: Please note that the default home directory for apache on Ubuntu xenial xepus is `/var/www/html`

Comment: Was there an index.html file in HTML folder or in www folder ?

Comment: Yes, there is an html file. I changed the default home directory.